# Counting how many times any of the items appear in a Scala List

Tags: scala

I have the following list:

```
val list = List("this", "this", "that", "there", "here", "their", "where")
```

I want to count how many times "this" OR "that" appears. I can do something like:

```
 list.count(_ == "this") + list.count(_ == "that")
```

Is there most concise way of doing this?

Comment: list.count(l => l == "this" || l == "that"). Does this work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `count` more than one occurrence at a time. No need to call `count` twice.

```
scala> list.count(x => x == "this" || x == "that")
res4: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> list.count(Set("this", "that").contains)
res12: Int = 3
```

- it's shorter
- it's one-pass

If you need to count words in several different places using the same big list:

```
val m = list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).withDefaultValue(0)
```

will give you a handy `Map` with all counts, so you could do

```
scala> m("this") + m("that")
res11: Int = 3
```

Comment: add `"` after `this`

Answer (score 2):

Very similar example:

```
  val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")

  s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

And result is

```
Map(banana -> 1, oranges -> 3, apple -> 3)
```

And for certain item:

```
s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)("apple")
```